# Processing an excel CSV in python scientific notation issue

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a CSV generated from a frequency counter into Python.  When opened in excel the rows have scientific notation:

1.00E+07

How would I convert this to a float with the right number of decimal places?

A simple type conversion to float didn't work and returned

10000000.0 when I need to extract

10000100.2326908

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure of how you got data your spreadsheet (as you don't really comment on it). Maybe you can bypass the problem by casting your floats to string (with the desired format/number of digt) into python before sending the data to Excel?

Comment: Check the CSV using a text editor, like Notepad.  Is it stored as scientific notation?  If so, you've already lost the information you want and need to pull the data in a different way.  If it's stored as you want, then it doesn't matter how Excel displays it.  Python will read it as strings written as they are in the CSV and they should be castable to float().

Comment: I am reading data from an existing spreadsheet in Excel that is csv format, which was generated from a frequency counter.  I am using a csv reader to extract each row but I am struggling to convert it to a useable format for data processing in python.  The file only shows scientific format in Notepad but the data is in the file - excel shows the correct number of decimal points when the formatting is changed.

Comment: It looks like you lost your data when you wrote to the CSV.

Comment: Is the original data CSV?  If so, you don't need Excel at all.  Are you using Excel to create a CSV from a different format?  If so, make sure Excel isn't casting the information into a different format before saving.

Comment: That was right - when I saved the file from one location to another the information was lost.

Answer (score 0):

@Talbarran

You need to edit the CSV data to:

```
 CVS_data_edited = 10000100.2326908
 print('{0:.7f}'.format (CVS_data_edited),'Print 7 places after the decimal')
```